# How do I `export * as foo from './foo'`?

Tags: typescript, es6-modules

TypeScript supports [re-exports](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html#re-exports), whereby a module can export a value imported from another module:

```
export {ZipCodeValidator as RegExpBasedZipCodeValidator} from "./ZipCodeValidator";
```

It also supports wildcard exports:

```
export * from "./StringValidator";
```

However, it does **not** support this syntax ([Microsoft/TypeScript#1215](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1215) discusses the syntax, which comes from ES6 and does not include this form):

```
export * as StringValidator from "./StringValidator"
```

The reason I'd like to do this is so I can split my module up into separate files, and have the TypeScript equivalent of a declaration like this:

```
module.exports = {
    foo: require('./foo'),
    bar: require('./bar'),
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [Daniel Tabuenca on Gitter](https://gitter.im/Microsoft/TypeScript?at=591b3c8c33e9ee771cb2c90c):

```
import * as foo from './foo'
import * as bar from './bar'
export {foo, bar}
```